# Facebook batch upload using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, batch-file

I have to upload multiple photos in facebook using batch process  Right now am uploading using this loop. It is working properly . But how to implement this with batch

```
for (var u=0; u < len; u++) { 
    var  dat = obj[u].url;

    FB.api('/'+ids+'/photos', 'post', {
        message: 'rose',
        status: 'success',
        access_token: FB.getAuthResponse().accessToken , 
        url: dat
    }, function (response) {
        // $('.ftab_prog').hide();
        if (!response || response.error)
            showError("Couldn't upload the photo. Please try again later.");
        else
            showInfo("Posted photo '<b>"+bn+"</b>' to facebook successfully!");
    });

}
```

Comment: take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/ and look at the bottom of the page, the section titled "Uploading binary data" should be a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already have working javascript code, why not use CScript to host it from the command line. See [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/488763/how-to-run-js-file-from-a-command-line-on-windows).